# C programming in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

Can I use Visual Studio to learn C programming? In the new project menu I can choose between Visual Basic, Visual C#, Visual C++, Visual F# and others but I don't see "C" or "Visual C".

Comment: VS only supports a subset of C89, if you need a real C compiler on windows you'll need mingw-64

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 has much better support for C than 2012.

Comment: I have books and video tutorials but they all have their own recommendations when it comes to the tools used to compile and write the code. I just want something I'm familiar with.

Comment: Just learn C the hard way : an IDE can slow you down when learning a new language. See the note on bottom of this page http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex0.html

Comment: @JérômeRadix though in exactly the same paragraph he says "An IDE, or "Integrated Development Environment" will turn you stupid. "   and "They are useful if you're trying to get something done"   He then says they are pointless for C (but that seems to be because he hasn't found a good one). I'm sure that if writing a GUI  / learning to write a GUI, and of course using libraries, then if there is a good IDE for C, it'd be very useful, not pointless.

Comment: Saying an IDE will turn you stupid to me is akin to saying a debugger or disassembler will turn you stupid. It's a tool. Know its place and know that it's no replacement for learning the fundamentals. Don't make it into bogeymen because some people use it to avoid having to learn.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, you need to rename .cpp files to c, so you can write C:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

From the link above:

> By default, the Visual C++ compiler treats all files that end in .c as C source code, and all files that end in .cpp as C++ source code. To force the compiler to treat all files as C regardless of file name extension, use the /Tc compiler option.

That being said, I do not recommend learning C language in Visual Studio, why VS? It does have lots of features you are not going to use while learning C

Comment: Often "learning C" (or C++) is the easy part - the hard part is learning how to build useful (often GUI) applications, which requires getting familiar with all sorts of libraries and frameworks, and IDE makes this experience a lot more manageable.

Comment: I'm already familiar with Visual Studio using other languages.

Comment: Just to make sure, check that the /TP compilation flag is not set.  If the flag is set, it will build .c programs as C++.

Answer (score 66):

Yes, you very well can learn C using Visual Studio.

Visual Studio comes with its own C compiler, which is actually the C++ compiler. Just use the `.c` file extension to save your source code.

You don't have to be using the IDE to compile C. You can write the source in Notepad, and compile it in command line using *Developer Command Prompt* which comes with Visual Studio.

Open the Developer Command Prompt, enter the directory you are working in, use the `cl` command to compile your C code.

For example, `cl helloworld.c` compiles a file named `helloworld.c`.

Refer this for more information: [Walkthrough: Compiling a C Program on the Command Line](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384838.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 20):

Yes it is, none of the Visual Stdio editions have C mentioned, but it is included with the C++ compiler (you therefore need to look under C++).  The main difference between using C and C++ is the naming system (i.e. using *.c* and not *.cpp*).

You do have to be careful not to create a C++ project and rename it to C though, **that does not work**.

## Coding C from the command line:

Much like you can use `gcc` on Linux (or if you have MinGW installed) Visual Studio has a command to be used from command prompt (it must be the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt though). As mentioned in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821416/c-programming-in-visual-studio/32187564#32187564) you can use `cl` to compile your c file (make sure it is named *.c*)

Example:

```
cl myfile.c
```

Or to check all the accepted commands:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>cl
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27030.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: cl [ option... ] filename... [ /link linkoption... ]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>
```

## Coding C from the IDE:

Without doubt one of the best features of Visual Studio is the convenient IDE.

Although it takes more configuring, you get bonuses such as basic debugging before compiling (for example if you forget a `;`)

To create a C project do the following:

Start a new project, go under C++ and select **`Empty Project`**, enter the **`Name`** of your project and the **`Location`** you want it to install to, then click **`Ok`**.  Now wait for the project to be created.

[image]

Next under **`Solutions Explorer`** right click **`Source Files`**, select **`Add`** then **`New Item`**.  You should see something like this:

[image]

Rename **`Source.cpp`** to include a **`.c`** extension (`Source.c` for example).  Select the location you want to keep it in,  I would recommend always keeping it within the project folder itself (in this case `C:\Users\Simon\Desktop\Learn\My First C Code`)

It should open up the `.c` file, ready to be modified.  Visual Studio can now be used as normal, happy coding!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can:

> You can create a C-language project by using C++ project templates. In the generated project, locate files that have a .cpp file name extension and change it to .c. Then, on the Project Properties page for the project (not for the solution), expand Configuration Properties, C/C++ and select Advanced. Change the Compile As setting to Compile as C Code (/TC).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/visual-cpp-project-types?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 3):

You can use Visual Studio for C, but if you are serious about learning the newest C available, I recommend using something like Code::Blocks with MinGW-TDM version, which you can get a 32 bit version of.  I use version 5.1 which supports the newest C and C++.  Another benefit is that it is a better platform for creating software that can be easily ported to other platforms.  If you were, for example, to code in C, using the SDL library, you could create software that could be recompiled with little to no changes to the code, on Linux, Apple and many mobile devices.  The way Microsoft has been going these days, I think this is definitely the better route to take.

Comment: Your help is appreciated, seriously. Sorry for my message possibly being too harsh. I agree that your answer may be useful to someone. Now I'm just trying to give you feedback so you can write better posts. I want to say that this does not provide answer for OP's question about how to write in C with MS VS.

Answer (score 0):

Download visual studio c++ express version 2006,2010 etc.
then goto create new project  and create c++ project select cmd project check empty rename cc with c extension  file name