# Comma separated expressions in printf() gives an unexpected result

Tags: c, printf, assignment-operator

I'm sorry if it is too conspicuous but I'm a bit obscure here.

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a = 8 , b = 7 ;
    int temp;
    printf("%d\n", temp=a,a=b,b=temp);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives a warning with
OUTPUT: `0`
According to me, The output should have been `8`, for I've tried this kind of code `printf("%d",a,b);` It prints the value of a that leads me to a conclusion that first expression will be printed with a warning of ***too many arguments for format***.
So, In my case when `temp=a` has to be the answer and hence the value of temp which became `8` should be printed.

Please explain, Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide

Answer (score 3):

From [Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order): *[emphasis added]*

> Order of evaluation of the operands of any C operator, **including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression**, and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression is **unspecified** (except where noted below). The compiler will evaluate them in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.

Since the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. The arguments you are passing to `printf()` includes both read and write of same variable and there is no sequence point, this will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

From C Standards#6.5p2

> 2 If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined...

---

### EDIT

In case if you are confused with comma as operator and comma as separator, the comma is a separator in the function argument list.

For reference, quoting an example from C Standards#6.5.17p3

> 3 EXAMPLE As indicated by the syntax, the comma operator (as described in this subclause) cannot appear in contexts where a **comma is used to separate items in a list (such as arguments to functions or lists of initializers).** On the other hand, it can be used within a parenthesized expression or within the second expression of a conditional operator in such contexts. In the function call

> ```
>       f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)
> ```

> the function has three arguments, the second of which has the value 5.

In the example above:

```
     Here comma is operator, so the expression will be evaluated to 5 (3+2)
         |
         | 
f(a, (t=3, t+2), c)
   |           |
   |           |
   -------------
        |
   here, comma is separator
```

Comment: Sorry for being persistent on this but you said the order of evaluation is unspecified. Is it true for every operator? Like if I write like this (++a)&&(--a)&&(a++). Will this also give undefined behaviour?

Comment: yes but no, `&&` is one of those that force strict sequencing, so side effects of the lhs will be settled before rhs is evaluated, if it is even evaluated...

Comment: unspecified evaluation is not all, but the fact that they are unsequenced too.

Comment: @VinayYadav Check the "Order of evaluation" link provided with answer. In that link, go through the "Ordering" and "Rules" section.

Comment: The title shows the asker believes the assignments are in “comma separated expressions,’ meaning expressions using C’s comma operator (C 2018 6.5.17). They are not, and this answer fails to correct that misbelief or explain why they are not in comma separated expressions.

Comment: @EricPostpischil In the question, OP clearly mentioned - `Comma separated expressions.....`. That means, OP is aware of the fact that comma in argument list is a separator and not operator. I have updated my answer to clarify the same, if there is any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Your expression

> ```
> printf("%d\n", temp = a, a = b, b = temp);
> //                     ^      ^ argument separator
> //             ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^ 3 arguments
> ```

no comma operator: 3 values to be printed (2 are evaluated but otherwise ignored), one conversion, **Undefined Behaviour** (unsequenced expressions).

What I think you were looking for

```
printf("%d\n", (temp = a, a = b, b = temp));
//                      ^      ^ comma operator
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 1 argument grouped
```

comma operator, 1 value, one conversion, no UB assuming temp is `int` and temp, b, and a are assignment compatible (which they are in your snippet).

Answer (score 2):

There is no comma operator in `printf("%d\n", temp=a,a=b,b=temp);`. In the argument list of a function call, commas separate arguments. They do not represent comma operators.

Thus, in `printf("%d\n", temp=a,a=b,b=temp);`, there are three separate expressions after the format string: `temp=a`, `a=b`, and `b=temp`.

The C standard does not specify the order in which function arguments, or even parts of function arguments, are evaluated. This causes your code to fall afoul of another rule that says if you both modify and use an object in an unsequenced way, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. For example, `a=b` uses `b`, and `b=temp` modifies `b`, and these are not sequenced, so the behavior is not defined. While the result is often as if the expressions were evaluated in one order or another, a program with this error may misbehave in other ways.

You can use a comma operator in a function call, but you have to use parentheses to distinguish it from function arguments, as in `printf("%d\n", (temp = a, a = b, b = temp));`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer by H.S. is correct that the order of evaluation of arguments is unspecified in the C-language spec.  Arguments can be evaluated in ***any*** order.

It is relatively common that the order of evaluation is typically backwards (from the right-most argument to the first argument).  This is because of the details of argument ordering on the stack.

We can deduce that the arguments are evaluated this way:

1. `b = temp` :: `temp` is undefined, but likely zero, therefore `b` is likely zero.
2. `a = b`  :: If `b` was zero, then `a` is now zero.
3. `temp = a` :: `temp` gets assigned the value of `a`, which was probably zero, but might've been the uninitialized value of `temp`. This is the argument that `printf` uses to format `%d`.  The extra arguments are not used (and probably generate a warning)
4. `"%d\n"` :: Not much to evaluate here, just a static string.

Although the output could be anything (including nasal demons), this helps explain why the output is frequently `0`.

Comment: The order of evaluation is unspecified, not undefined

Comment: @abelenky you said the order of evaluation is unspecified/undefined but then U delineated the flow of the program. So, can we do this always like moving from the right-most argument to the first argument?

Comment: this misses the point. the evaluations od arguments are *unsequenced* wrt each other and that, along with modifying and reading the same variable gets us into a trouble.

Comment: *"It is relatively common that the order of evaluation is typically backwards"*  This is correct:  The order can be **any** order, but it is *often* backwards.  You cannot rely on backwards behavior, but it does help explain the observed result.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is not initialising temp.
The expression " b = temp "
Will return an error.
To have 8 as the result

```
printf("%d\n", temp = b, b = a)
```

You can evaluate the code and just use a single variable inside printf

**Edit**
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637712/sequence-points-between-printf-function-args-does-the-sequence-point-between-co) answer you cannot say the evaluation will be from right to left as it is undefined.

Comment: This still causes undefined behaviour (`b` is written and read without a sequence point)