# C support in visual studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio

Not C# or C++, but C. Is there any C support in Visual Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C programming in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821416/c-programming-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the *Visual Studio Installer* if you click on your already installed version of Visual Studio (*in the image I clicked on my VS 2017 Community*).

> Under **Individual components** --> *Compilers, build tools and run-times* you can check `Clang/C2`. Clang is a `C` compiler.

**Answer:** by default it appears not, but you can install the Clang component and it appears you will be able to.

[image]