# Legal or not legal in C

Tags: c, arrays, declaration

When declaring arrays in C, is it allowed to use this:

```
int arrSize = 10;
float weight[arrSize];
```

How would this affect the compiler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427336/why-cant-i-create-an-array-with-size-determined-by-a-global-variable

Comment: That's a "variable-length array" ("VLA").  Legal since C99, I think, as long as it's a local (not global) variable..

Comment: I still did not get the safety concern..can you elaborate?

Comment: What does mean __safe__ in your context?

Comment: i meant "safe" to be "legal". Thank for the asnwer

Comment: @OsamaAbaali you can [edit]  your question

Comment: I think that it should be said that although this may be legal, but using this method to create large arrays can be dangerous, since the stack size is relatively small.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I create an array with size determined by a global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427336/why-cant-i-create-an-array-with-size-determined-by-a-global-variable)

Comment: @PeterMiehle That's a bad duplicate, not at all related to this question. In the proposed "duplicate", the problem is providing an initializer list to a VLA, which is not the case here.

Comment: upps verklickt.

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed in C99 but optional from C11 and later, assuming it's inside a function (not a global file-level scope). It will generally allocate the array on the stack, and `sizeof` on the array will also work and thus be a run-time operation on that particular variable.

If not allowed, it won't build, of course.

Comment: Note that VLAs are an optional feature in C11.

Comment: @nwellnhof I always forget. Thanks.

Comment: This is where Visual Studio's C99 support ends, so if portability in that direction is important for you, then don't use VLAs.

Comment: @RuudHelderman If portable C is important to you, then obviously don't use the non-portable, non-compliant, non-C Visual Studio compiler. Programs written for that one are very unlikely to work if ported to a conforming compiler.

Comment: @Lundin I know, you know, but [many people do not know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821416/c-programming-in-visual-studio). And there's people who know but are at the mercy of company policy. But thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Such a declaration of a Variable Length Array (VLA)

```
int arrSize = 10;
float weight[arrSize];
```

is allowed for arrays with automatic storage duration that is inside a block scope. This feature was introduced in C99. Now such a feature is optional.

Also you can use multidimensional VLAs and declare function parameters as VLAs.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void set_array( size_t, size_t, int[][*] );
void display_array( size_t, size_t, int [*][*] );

void set_array( size_t m, size_t n, int a[m][n] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            a[i][j] = n * i + j;
        }
    }
}

void display_array( size_t m, size_t n, int a[][n] )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t m = 2;
    size_t n = 3;
    int a[m][n];

    set_array( m, n, a );
    display_array( m, n, a );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5
```

Answer (score -1):

In C90, this code is illegal, because Variable-length arrays cannot be declared. Even though `arrSize` is an integer value, it still has a place in memory, and cannot be used in this context.

If you are using C, you can place a "define" statement in a header file or at the top of the program:

```
#define arrSize 10
...
float weight[arrSize];
```

Or if using C++, the following can work:

```
const int arrSize = 10;
float weight[arrSize];
```

Comment: Please don't tell a C programmer to (maybe) use C++; these are vastly different languages.

Comment: True. Was just taking into account the context of the asker. It didn't seem like a complicated question, so it could have been from a student who was learning both.

Comment: What about giving an answer in standard C, instead of non-standard C and another programming language...